# Unable to delete Postgres database using CLI

Tags: database, postgresql, bash, azure, command-line-interface

I am unable to delete PostgreSQL database in azure using the below command:

```
az PostgreSQL db delete
```

Is there any other script such as bash to clean up azure postgreSQL database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not say postgresql but postgres - *az postgres db delete*

Answer (score 0):

Try command to like Delete database 'testdb' in the server 'testsvr':

`az postgres db delete -g testgroup -s testsvr -n testdb`

Required Parameters
--name -n
The name of the database.

Optional Parameters
--ids
One or more resource IDs (space-delimited). It should be a complete resource ID containing all information of 'Resource Id' arguments. You should provide either --ids or other 'Resource Id' arguments.

--resource-group -g
Name of resource group. You can configure the default group using az configure --defaults group=.

--server-name -s
Name of the server. The name can contain only lowercase letters, numbers, and the hyphen (-) character. Minimum 3 characters and maximum 63 characters.

--yes -y
Do not prompt for confirmation.

To delete the Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server, run:

```
az postgres flexible-server delete --resource-group myresourcegroup --name 
mydemoserver
```

Comment: Thanks @Shakti .. I am looking for a script by which we can clean up azure Postgres db along with the related azure resources that has been created while creating the Postgres db such as private endpoint, private dns zone and extensions.
I know by using az group delete --name $resourcegroup ,we can clean up all the resources but it will delete all the resources present on the resource group. but is there any script to delete the linked resources to the specific Postgres db.

Comment: Can you please check the above comment.

Comment: I tried to execute command "az postgres flexible-server delete --resource-group myresourcegroup --name 
mydemoserver" which deleted Postgres Flexible server from the Resource Group. Could you please show the extensions which are talking about still shown in your RG?

Comment: While creating the Postgres flexible-server, for private connection we have created private endpoint and private dns zone and connected it with virtual networks. So, now when we delete the sql db using above mentioned cmd, will these private endpoint and private dns zone will also get deleted or we need to delete them separately. I think we need to delete those resources manually.